# magento change checkout url in top menu

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9

In Magento ,add one step checkout extension.Its works fine but top menu Checkout link is redirect to **mydomain/checkout/onepage**.Actually what I need is Checkout link is redirect to **mydomain/onestepcheckout**

Thanks

Comment: which verions you have use?

Comment: Magento 1.9.1 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I donot know  which magento  version you have using .

According to basic magento code this link has been coming  from  `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links` class `addCheckoutLink` function.

If you have `rewrite`  this class  then and `modify code then it will works`

### Rewrite class at config.xml

```
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <magento57995>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento57995_Block</class>
      </magento57995>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <links>Stackexchange_Magento57995_Block_Checkout_Links</links>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
    </blocks>
  </global>
```

### Rewrite class code and edit function addCheckoutLink

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento57995_Block_Checkout_Links extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Links
{

        public function addCheckoutLink()
    {
        if (!$this->helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            $text = $this->__('Checkout');
            $parentBlock->addLink(
                $text, 'onestepcheckout', $text,
                true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
                'class="top-link-checkout"'
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank You sir,Good Effort.I use that code nothing will happen.

Comment: Bala, I have check the it was working.. May be you not create extension

Comment: Thanks,another extension overwrite Mage_Checkout_Block_Links.So I find my problem

Comment: I also add my answer for my question

Answer (score 3):

Lotusbreath one step checkout extension is used
My code is

```
public function addCheckoutLink()
{

    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('lotusbreath_onestepcheckout/general/enabled')) {
        return parent::addCheckoutLink();
    }

    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
    if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Lotusbreath_OneStepCheckout')) {
        $text = $this->__('Checkout');
        $parentBlock->addLink(
            $text, 'lotusbreath_onestepcheckout', $text,
            true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
            'class="top-link-checkout"'
        );
    }
    return $this;
}}
```